# Submitting button data in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to understand how to implement the following concept:

[What I am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/151XS.png)

A user can type in their username + room, and then click on a button to indicate the color they want.

So far I have the username + room part working, it is passed in the URL as parameters. But what if I wanted to pass (through URL params) which color button was pressed as well? Since the buttons aren't input elements, the data isn't passed through the URL, but I want it to be. Here is what the form looks like so far:

```
<form action="/reaction.html">
    <label>Choose a username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="insert username" requried autocomplete="off">
    <label>Room name:</label>
    <input type="text" name='room' placeholder='insert room' required autocomplete="off">
    <label>Chose your color:</label>
    <div class="colors">
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonred" name="red"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonblue" name="blue"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttongreen" name="green"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonyellow" name="yellow"></button>
    </div>
    <button class="submitbutton">Join</button> 
</form>
```

To make it clear right now I get something like: "http://localhost:3000/reaction.html?username=a&room=a" when submitting the form, I want to find a way to add a param at the end, maybe something like "?color=red".

I know I probably need to attach onclick listeners for each button, but what to do after listening for a click?

Comment: have you tried creating a hidden input? 
1- create an event on click of buttons
2- set the data attribute of button as input value

Comment: Try using `<input type="submit" name="color-red" value="red" />` you will get the query like `?color-red=red`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with button approach only, try to create a hidden input and set the value on click event of color button

```
<form action="/reaction.html">
    <label>Choose a username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="insert username" requried autocomplete="off">
    <label>Room name:</label>
    <input type="text" name='room' placeholder='insert room' required autocomplete="off">
    <label>Chose your color:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="color" id="color">
    <div class="colors">
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonred" data-value="red">Red</button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonblue" data-value="blue">Blue</button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttongreen" data-value="green">Green</button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonyellow" data-value="yellow">Yellow</button>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submitbutton">Join</button> 
</form>
```

Script part

```
$('.buttonround').click(function(e) {
    $('#color').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Other possible way is to create a custom radio button. Please refer this code for radio button which looks like a button. https://codepen.io/salfx/pen/ZXOVjo

Comment: Great, if this code works for you, please remember to mark my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet. You will need to remove the `ev.preventDefault();` to actually allow the submission of the form after the `join` button is pressed.

```js
const frm=document.querySelector('form');
frm.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  if (ev.target.tagName=='BUTTON') {
    if (ev.target.className=='sbutton') {
      ev.preventDefault();  // for testing ...
      console.log([...frm.querySelectorAll('input')].map(el=>[el.name,el.value]));
    } else 
      frm.color.value=ev.target.name; 
  }
});
```

```css
input {display:block}
.buttonround {width:40px; height:40px; border-radius:20px; border:none} 
.buttonred{background-color:red}
.buttonblue{background-color:blue}
.buttongreen{background-color:green}
.buttonyellow{background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<form action="/reaction.html">
    <label>Choose a username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="insert username" requried autocomplete="off">
    <label>Room name:</label>
    <input type="text" name='room' placeholder='insert room' required autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="color">
    <label>Chose your color:</label>
    <div class="colors">
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonred" name="red"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonblue" name="blue"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttongreen" name="green"></button>
         <button type="button" class="buttonround buttonyellow" name="yellow"></button>
    </div>
    <button class="sbutton">Join</button> 
</form>
```